# Combinations without using "itertools.combinations"

Tags: python, combinations

What I'd need is to create combinations for two elements a time.

If a list contains: `seq = ['A', 'B', 'C']` 
the output would be `com = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C']]`

all this without `itertools.combinations` method.

I used the following code for the permutations. But how could I modify it to make it work with the combinations?

```
def permute(seq):

    if len(seq) <= 1:
        perms = [seq]
    else:
        perms = []
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            sub = permute(seq[:i]+seq[i+1:]) 
            for p in sub:    
                perms.append(seq[i:i+1]+p)

return perms
```

Comment: Why *without* `itertools`?

Comment: The equivalent source code for `combinations` is on the `itertools` documentation page. Just copy-paste it into your file.

Comment: Yea, I can't use alternative methods. Thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the `itertools.combinations` function returns lexicographic sort order which may be undesirable for lists of integers - ie `combinations([1,2,10,3], 3)` yields `[1,2,10]` before `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use `itertools`, then use the [documented pure-Python equivalent](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: What's the Big O time complexity of this?  I think it's `O(r * (n! / (r! (n - r)!)))`:  the `while` loops `nCr` times, and `tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)` makes each loop have `O(r)` work.  So this iterative solution looks much more efficient than the [recursive backtracking solution](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/), which I think is `O(n^r)`.

Comment: I haven't done an analysis of the complexity; at a glance I think you got the complexity correct. It certainly is well below O(nr).

Comment: Which `if` statement is that `else` inside the `while` loop associated with? I've never seen this before.

Comment: @c_sagan: it isn't associated with any `if` statement, it's associated with the `for` loop. In python, `while` and `for` have `else` blocks too, executed when the loop *completes without exiting through a `break`*.

Comment: @c_sagan: so in this case, `else: return` executes when the current element index reaches the highest value it can reach (e.g. for 10 inputs with 3 combinations, that's indices 7, 8 and 9).

Comment: @MartijnPieters the complexity is o(#combinations) which is o(n choose r) which is o(n^(max(n-r, r)))

Comment: @Gulzar: I simply quoted the documentation, this is not my own code. The code deals with *indices* into the iterable, finding the first index from the end that *can* be incremented, then after incrementing that value, propagating the next higher value to the next index, etc. The indices are then used to select the values from the input iterable.

Comment: @Gulzar: so, for the input `iterable=[0, 1, 2, 3], r=3`, you start with indexes `[0, 1, 2]`, see that the 3rd index can be incremented so you get `[0, 1, 3]`, see you can't increment the 3rd index further so move to the 2nd index and get `[0, 2, 3]`, then move to the first index and you get `[1, 2, 3]`. Note how this matches the documented example in the docstring.

Answer (score 8):

This is trivial to do directly:

```
def comb2(s):
    for i, v1 in enumerate(s):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
            yield [v1, s[j]]
```

Then:

```
print list(comb2(['A', 'B', 'C']))
```

displays:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C']]
```

The only thing that makes combinations at all tricky is catering to a known-only-at-runtime number of elements to take at a time.  So long as you know that number in advance, a fixed number of loops nested that deep does the job in an obvious way.

Answer (score 6):

```
def combo2(lst,n):
    if n==0:
        return [[]]
    l=[]
    for i in range(0,len(lst)):
        m=lst[i]
        remLst=lst[i+1:]
        for p in combo2(remLst,n-1):
            l.append([m]+p)
    return l
```

Input:

```
combo2(list('ABC'),2)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a loose translation of the recursive C++ code in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292370/recursive-combinations/7299332#7299332) to a similar question:

```
def combinations(sequence, length, NULL=object()):
    """ Find all combinations of the specified length from a sequence. """
    if length <= 0:
        combos = [NULL]
    else:
        combos = []
        for i, item in enumerate(sequence, 1):
            rem_items = sequence[i:]
            rem_combos = combinations(rem_items, length-1)
            combos.extend(item if combo is NULL else [item, combo]
                            for combo in rem_combos)
    return combos

print(combinations(['A', 'B', 'C'], 2))
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Combination in pure python

```
# generate combination of two list
import copy
def extend_list(list1,list2):
    temp=[];temp=copy.deepcopy(list1);temp.append(list2)
    return temp
def combination(list1, list2):
    return [extend_list(item1,item2) if type(item1) is list else [item1,item2] for item1 in list1 for item2 in list2]

# generate all combination of list of variables
def list_combination(list_of_variables):
    '''list_of_variables is a list of list e.g [[1,2],['True','False']]'''
    node_combinations=[]
    no_of_variables=len(list_of_variables)
    node_combinations=list_of_variables[0]
    for i in range(no_of_variables-1):
        node_combination = combination(node_combinations,list_of_variables[i+1])
        node_combinations=node_combination
    return node_combinations
```

#### Output

```
input_list = [['TRUE', 'FALSE'], [1, 2], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']]
list_combination(input_list)

[['TRUE', 1, 'TRUE'],
 ['TRUE', 1, 'FALSE'],
 ['TRUE', 2, 'TRUE'],
 ['TRUE', 2, 'FALSE'],
 ['FALSE', 1, 'TRUE'],
 ['FALSE', 1, 'FALSE'],
 ['FALSE', 2, 'TRUE'],
 ['FALSE', 2, 'FALSE']]
```