# Multiple variables to iterate over a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to have multiple iterators that go over the same list in a for-loop, something like

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
Triples = []
for i,j,k in range(len(x)):
    print(i,j,k)
```

Result:

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
...
```

Is this possible in python?

My idea is to make the variable i as a reference for j and k.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this? it seems like you could just do `print(i,i,i)`, no?

Comment: Seems like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/513348).

Comment: Can you do the same with `for i... in...:` followed by `j = k = i`

Comment: You might as well use a single ""iterator"" `i` and just do `j = k = i` inside the loop

Comment: So you cant initialise a for-loop like that?

Comment: @Jack, ofc you can, but doing this in example you provided looking kinda absurd. Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66642691/edit) your question including some real-world example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print("elements")
for i, j, k in zip(x, x, x):
    print(i, j, k)

print("\nindexes")
for i, j, k in zip(range(len(x)), range(len(x)), range(len(x))):
    print(i, j, k)
```

output:

```
elements
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4

indexes
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I had in mind. Appreciate the answer. Is there any way to achieve this using the same list?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this?

```
import itertools
x = range(1, 5)
print(x)
print(list(itertools.combinations(x, 3)))
# [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: Yes that is actually the final outcome I would like, but I wanted to try solving this without using the `itertools.combinations` function to help me learn.

Comment: @Jack, there's search box on the top, [*sometimes*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20764926/10824407) it's useful.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Please explain what a "search box" is, your instructions are unclear.